# Is it possible to check how long ago was an nfs volume mounted?

Tags: linux, nfs

Is there a way to see how long ago a volume was mounted without using the log files?

Basically, I have a list of mounted volumes over nfs and I need to see if they were mounted today or months ago.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can cat:

```
/proc/self/mountstats
```

And there's a parameter below the mount point called "age" that specified the time in seconds since the nfs volume was mounted.